# Virtual environment not appearing on anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

I worked on a project on an isolated virtual environment, I created the virtual environment using the following code.

```
python -m venv project_env
```

Later on, I wanted to learn more about package management and conda commands. But whenever I type:

```
conda env list
```

I only get the base environment. Now my confusion became clearer about why this is happening as I made the project environment using pip (or python) commands and not conda commands.

So now I have two questions, what are the best practices when creating virtual environments? Is it possible to move the package I created using pip to anaconda?

Comment: you need to install venv package, if you want to create virtual environment from it . ]

Answer (score 0):

```
conda create --name VenvName
```

**When conda asks you to proceed, type y**

```
proceed ([y]/n)?
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Engr Tanveer sultan suggested.

when you create a virtual environment using command

```
conda create --name VenvName
```

Conda asks you if you want to `proceed ([y]/n)?`
Proceed by typing y.

Use the command below to list all the available virtual environments.

```
conda env list
```

Reference - https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment

If you create a virtual environment using the command `virtualenv` use the command `lsvirtualenv` to list all virtual environment.
Reference - https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html